# $watch not working with data model factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rather large app i'm building, and want to make sure i get this right.

The first watch is empty as expected.

But watch isnt fired a second time when the http call completes.

**But the brands from the http call are on the scope since using ng-repeat works.**

I'd rather not use $broadcast because i feel like it over complicates some of my directives that use $watch as well.

Heres a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/L1SNV7mt6x7XCF4QFDPk?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', function($scope, $http, Brand) {

  $scope.brands = Brand.all;

  $scope.$watch('brands', function(old, neww) {
    console.log('brands', old, neww);
  });

});

app.factory('Brand', function($http) {

  var brands = {
    all: [],
    add: function(item) {
      brands.all.push(item);
    },
    get: function() {
      brands.all = [];
      $http.get('json.txt').success(function(data) {
        _.each(data, function(brand){
          brands.add(Model(brand));
        });
      });
    }
  };

  var Model = function(item) {
    return item;
  };

  brands.get();

  return brands;
});
```

Comment: The plunker works for me? What are you expecting in the console?

Comment: apologies - it worked the first time, then I refreshed the page and got two blank arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set 3d parameter in `$watch` to `true`:

```
$scope.$watch('brands', function(old, neww) {
   console.log('brands', old, neww);
}, true);
```

It will say angular to watch deeper.
[Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Comment: This may work in trivial cases, but it can be inefficient for large or complex graphs and arrays. I've even had it just plain not work with arrays the way I expect (though those may have just been simple bugs).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how AngularJS detects changes in items it watches. For simply watching if the elements are added or removed from an array, you'll want to use [`$watchCollection`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) instead of `$watch`.

[Updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/plGr0ugjXGQwa2ytuXqU?p=preview).

Comment: I saw your comment after accepting an answer, and yours seems to sort of work, it doesn't show the correct old scope, should be an empty array

Comment: Hadn't noticed before. [There is a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621) regarding `oldValue` that will be fixed in 1.2.15. So, `$watch` deeper will still be your solution for now. Just be aware of the performance implications of a deep watch if you have lots of Brands, or the graph for each brand is large, and consider changing it once the bug is fixed. If neither case is true for you, then never mind.